# How to expose part of Python program as COM server

Tags: python, com, win32com

I have python application (bundled using py2exe) that runs as background system-tray application which monitor specific folder (like Dropbox) for any file add/create and backup that file into the cloud.

I want one feature added to that application i.e. expose API as COM server so another application can use it by passing the file path and get that file backed-up into cloud.

I have gone through this [link](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Windows-Programming-in-Python-Creating-COM-Servers/3/) on how to create COM server and I feel I'm close to get this things happen with following issue:

1. Every time I run my application it register the COM and hence ask Administrator's permission
2. What is the way to register COM without asking Administrator permission. My application distributed as installer made by Inno setup.
3. I need my application open automatically (if it is closed) when other application access COM object (registered by my application)

Comment: Let the installer register your COM server. Inno Setup has the [`RegisterServer`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registerserver) function for it.

Comment: Thanks for great idea. I know how to register COM server class inside python program using:
win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(MyClass)

I'm not sure how to do this inside Inno Setup since my COM server class inside .exe file built using py2exe.

Comment: I don't know anything about py2exe, but you can simply try to register your DLL from command line by using `regsvr32.exe` and if that succeed, then you can use `RegisterServer` function from Inno Setup. The point of this test is to try if your library exposes the `DllRegisterServer` entry point.